# Actionbar Push up relative to screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have achieved hiding and showing the actionbar on scroll however I have a few problems with it. 1.) when I click on a tab in my application that requires the action bar to be show then return to the screen where the action bar can be hidden, there is a white space that is the exact size of the action bar under the action bar. 2.) There is an annoying flicker sometimes when the action bar is being hidden  or unhidden.

I have seen on many google applications and applications such as instagram where the action bar pushes up relative to the position on screen. I have searched for libraries or ideas on how to implement that technique but have not found any? Is there any way I can at least get rid of the actionbar flicker or is there a library where I can implement the actionbar push up on scroll in my application[image]?